# jquery weird error in jgrowl

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

All,

I use jgrowl to display certain content ,and i had got this weird error today

```
$(this).data("jGrowl") is undefined in jquery.jgrowl_compressed.js file in line 59
```

which points me to the followong line,

```
$(this).data("jGrowl").created=new Date();
```

And in my project js file i have the following code

```
if (data)
{
 $('.jGrowl-notification:contains("' + oldtext + '")').remove();
 $.jGrowl.defaults.poll = 1;
 $.jGrowl(data, { animateOpen: { height: 'show'}, glue : 'after' , position : 'bottom-right'});
  oldtext=data;
  clean();
 }

 function clean()
 {
  $('.jGrowl-notification:contains("' + oldtext + '")').remove();
 }
```

I get the error when i try to open the menu and before it opens i open it again..

Any idea what might be wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Edit:I have added more code to get the clarity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the API for `.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) the syntax should be `$(this).data("jGrowl_created", new Date());` or something like it. Perhaps you'd rather want `$(jGrowlElement).data("created", new Date()");`.

Comment: Yes the problem is related to this ,but i tried the thing you had told and jgrowl doesnt close by itself if we apply the above said things by you..

Comment: Perhaps it's a compability issue with jQuery and your version of jGrowl, because it seems the code from their library is written poorly (if "$(this).data("jGrowl").created=new Date();" is from their lib)

Comment: Try updating both jQuery and jGrowl. If that still doesn't work, I think you should correct the jGrowl code (if it indeed is wrong.)